# Styles and Triggers in TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers, styles

I'm trying to add `OuterGlowBitmapEffect` effect to `TextBox` when Mouse hovers it. 
I use triggers. Here is some code:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Margin="12,283,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Text="" />

<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Red" GlowSize="10"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But it's not working. What i missed?

Comment: You shouldn't be using [`BitmapEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.bitmapeffect.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`BitmapEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.bitmapeffect.aspx):

> [ObsoleteAttribute("BitmapEffects are deprecated and no longer function.  Consider using Effects where appropriate instead.")]

You can simulate a glow using the [`Effect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.effect.aspx) property with an instance of [`DropShadowEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="Red" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
```